# Excel - Cells are locking after VBA macro runs

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that's using a loop to take data from one sheet and copy it to another, putting them in an order determined by an array. Relevant code:

```
For counter = 1 To 358 Step 1
    Sheets("data").Cells(inputrow, counter + 1) = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(rowarray(counter), colarray(counter))
    Sheets("sheet1").Cells(rowarray(counter), colarray(counter)).Clear
Next counter
```

The input sheet is protected, with the cells that you put data unlocked, but every time I run the macro those cells get locked again. I have no idea what's causing this and it's driving me nuts. Please help!

Answer (score 3):

`.Clear` was stripping the unlocked formatting. Use `.ClearContents` instead.